# ECLIPSE: CreateProcess error=216 - Cannot run program "\java\jdk-11.0.14\bin\javaw.exe" in directory

Tags: java, eclipse, java-11

I just downloaded and installed latest version of eclipse.
Before that I had installed jdk 11 in location: `D:\learning\java\jdk-11.0.14`.
In eclipse, I added above location in installed JREs
[image]

**Compiler compliance level is also set to 11.**

But, when I try to run a normal hello world program, it gives me below error:
[image]

I tried to find solution online, but haven't found any solution yet.

In questions where CreateProcess error=216 is mentioned, it's coming in Android Studio.

Places where the first half of error is same, CreateProcess error is different or the reason is mentioned that system type are not compatible, but it doesn't seem to be the issue in my case. Since, my system type is 64 bit operating system, X64-based processor and setup that I downloaded from [here](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/oomph/epp/2022-03/R/eclipse-inst-jre-win64.exe) was also for 64 bit systems.

Please let me know if I have missed any information.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like it is the JDK that is the problem. What happens if you just run `D:\learning\java\jdk-11.0.14\bin\javaw.exe` from a command prompt?

Comment: I tried to access it today, it says directory is corrupted and unreadable. But till last night I was able to open the directory. Will try again the installation and see if that works.

Comment: So, after installation, I was trying to get rid of remaining folders turns out, some locations have become corruptible and unreadable, I'm not even able to delete them. I wonder what went wrong!! I have 2 JDKs but both in different drives, 2 eclipses, those also in 2 different drives

Comment: For now, I have moved to JDK 8, I'll try to get rid of corrupted folders first, then try again with JDK 11 and update. And while switching back to JDK8, make sure to make all necessary changes in eclipse, like compiler compliance level for project and in preferences, redirecting to JDK 8 in installed JREs.

Comment: So after removing all those corrupted locations, I reinstalled java 11, configured eclipse accordingly and program runs fine.